# Start page without filename and extension in the URL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am setting up a blank project in Visual Studio 2012 and have set my index.html as the start page. The problem I am having is that the URL now says "localhost:64237/app/index.html" as it is including the path to the index page.

I want to be able to type in "localhost:64237" and have it still access the index page, without showing me the rest of the path or the filename/extension in the URL.

Comment: Hi, i think you can't do that in ASP.NET. If you want hide the path you need a Domain and with that Domain hide your path.

Comment: @Ryuzaki: A simple route config does this. I think OP simply didn't create the right project type, or is missing the proper configuration.

Comment: What are you using to host this solution?  Since it is .NET, I assume it is most likely IIS?  Can you confirm?

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Part of it seems addressable by a `default document` setting. Depending on your application type, the other part of your question is either a `route` setting or some IIS configuration (it's own web site/application?)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project and go to properties. Select "web" on the left-hand side. Under the "servers" section, you should be able to set it up with out "app". Once that's done, it should work like you want. If not, look into IIS and Virtual Directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing.

By using routing you can change this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Product/ProductDetails.aspx?id=1
http://www.mywebsite.com/ProductProductDetails.aspx?name=Apple
```

into this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Product/1
http://www.mywebsite.com/Product/Apple
```

or this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/Apple
```

Find more info in google about ASP.NET Routing.

good luck